# Pregunta sobre Nessus?

Tags: linux, debian

He instaladado la version `1.0.6` de `kali` en vmware player y me he descargado la version de `64bits` `debian nessus`.

El problema es que cuando lo inicializo me sale un link que es `https://kali:8834`, pero cuando entro me lo rechaza poniendo error de conexión.

¿Qué puedo hacer para poder entrar?

Comment: Pues como suele ser habitual, depende bastante del error en concreto que te muestre... a ciegas poco se puede hacer, ¿no?

Comment: En efecto, cuando pueda lo vuelvo a explicar con mas detalle y con imagenes , merci por tu recomendación.

Comment: Puedes verificar que tu servicio de http este funcionando correctamente, también valida que los puertos estén abiertos y que las direcciones IP estén correctas, revisa permisos (de los archivos web de Nessus), si pudieras mandas un screen de lo que aparece o pegar el error en un comentario podríamos ver otras opciones. Saludos.